# How to set up EBS data usage alarm to CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ebs

I tried going through AWS documentation ([here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ec2-metricscollected.html), [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ebs-metricscollected.html), [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html)), but I couldn't find any information on how to get EBS data usage metrics to CloudWatch, and how to set up EBS data usage alarm.

I was able to set up data usage alarm for the instance using [`mon-put-instance-data.pl` script](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/mon-scripts.html#mon-scripts-using), but I want similar metrics and alarm also for the EBS. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

> EBS data usage metrics

Since every othet type of metric is already automatically available to Cloudwatch, I assume that you are referring to metrics of space used and space free.  That isn't information EBS has access to.

EBS is a block store -- it provides raw block devices, and thus has no intrinsic concept of "used" vs "free," because that is a filesystem concept, not a block device concept.  You can put any filesystem you want on an EBS volume, or, with a partition table, multiple filesystems.  EBS is content-agnostic, so it can't see this.  This isn't a limitation, it's intrinsic to the nature of what EBS is for.

To obtain used/free block information, you need a process running or scheduled to run (usually via `cron`) on your instance, such as the [`mon-put-instance-data.pl`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/mon-scripts.html#mon-scripts-using) script you mentioned... because such information is only available from the operating system, from inside the instance.

Comment: I know that I need such script, but how do I actually implement it? I didn't see any mention of EBS in the scripts provided by Amazon and couldn't find info on how to implement such script. It is hard to believe that there is not more information available, considering that this is likely very common use case for server maintainers.

Comment: See the `--disk-*` arguments for `mon-put-instance-data.pl`.  That's what those do... volume usage.

Comment: Aa, I think I just figured it out. With --disk-path it should be possible to select any mount point for gathering the metrics, i.e. instance filesystem or EBS volume. Actually just realized that the root file system (/dev/xvda1) of the instance happens to be EBS, and the instance filesystem (/dev/xvdb) is currently unused, so in the end the metrics I got were exactly what I wanted.

Comment: That's exactly the idea.